# How can i Get the name and value separately from the Key pair Value (from the Model)?

Tags: c#

I have initialized get set Property for this list in the model Now, I need to get the value and the name of that property in below mentioned for each loop

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry value in Model)
                {
                    // value.value (name) and value.Value 

                   // I need to get the values and key name in this For each loop
                }
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Key{0} = Value{1}", value.Key, value.Value);Here Value.Key is the Name.

Comment: `value.Key` and `value.Value`? What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry value in Model)
                {
                    var modelValue = value.Value;
                    var modelKey = value.Key;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration exposes each individual key value pair in the dictionary. So value will have a key and a value

```
value.Key
value.Value
```